# Using csv-parse without a loop

Tags: node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I'm using the [csv-parse](https://csv.js.org/parse/examples/) Node package to parse a CSV string.  The documentation suggests that I read the parsed result using something like this:

```
const output = []
parse(`
  "1","2","3"
  "a","b","c"
`)
.on('readable', function() {
  let record
  while (record = this.read()) {
    output.push(record)
  }
})
```

This approach angers the linting gods by assigning within a while loop (and having an unnamed function).  It also just doesn't make me feel great to begin with; I have a feeling there is a more concise and readable approach somewhere.

How can I populate a parsed result from the `csv-parse` stream without resorting to a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `ReadableStream` you can use `on('data', () => {})` instead if you prefer.

```
.on('data', (record) => output.push(record))
```

In any case, there's nothing wrong with that code, and it's the recommended approach by the `csv-parse` developers.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate that the original code was fine; I admit I strongly prefer what you offered in this answer, though.